# Centralizar uma div circular dentro de uma outra div

Tags: css, html5

Boa tarde !! 
Gostaria de fazer com que uma div circular ficasse centralizada em uma outra div maior, ela está focada na esquerda
podem me ajudar??

```css
 .conteudo-externo{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:3;
  background:#ff1;
  float:left;
 }
 .conteudo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:#000;
  position:left;
  background-image:'images\j2.png';
  }
  .img{
   z-index:1;
   width:130px;
                        height:130px
                        background-position:center;
   opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Teste</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="conteudo-externo">
  <div class="conteudo">
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Não existe float: center amigo.

Comment: :'(, vou editar lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade "position" não pode receber o valor "left";
Fiz pequenas mudanças na classe 'conteudo':

```
.conteudo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #000;
    /*
    position: left;
    background-image:'images\j2.png';
    */
    background-image: url('images\j2.png');
    margin: 50px auto;
}
```

Na propriedade margin passei 2 parâmetros (50px e 'auto').

- O 50px significa a margem do eixo Y, ou seja, 50px de margin-top;
- O 'auto' centraliza o elemento, mas só funciona se o elemento pai estiver com 'width' definido;

Espero ter ajudado;

Comment: Aaaah, entendi, muito obrigado @Veber, não tinha conhecimento disso !! vou ajustar aqui o restante

Answer (score 2):

```css
.conteudo-externo{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:3;
  background:#ff1;
  float:left;
 }
 .conteudo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:#000;
  position:left;
  background-image:'images\j2.png';
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  .img{
   z-index:1;
   width:130px;
                        height:130px
                        background-position:center;
   opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Teste</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="conteudo-externo">
  <div class="conteudo">
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Perfeito !!! muito obg !!!

Comment: apenas para conhecimento, a altura foi em hard code porque ele não consegue pegar automaticamente. A fórmula é a seguinte: Margintop = Altura_Contener - (Altura_objeto/2)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim...

```css
.conteudo-externo{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:3;
  background:#ff1;
  float:left;
 }
 .conteudo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:#000;
  position:left;
  background-image:'images\j2.png';
      margin: 0 auto
  }
  .img{
   z-index:1;
   width:130px;
                        height:130px
                        background-position:center;
   opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Teste</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="conteudo-externo">
  <div class="conteudo">
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
```