# Dúvida em JavaScript - Centralizar imagem

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tenho uma function que coloca imagens no background de uma div circular. 
Gostaria de centralizar a imagem no centro da div circular como no exemplo a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pensei em colocar um `background-position:center;` no JavaScript, será que dará certo?

```js
 function clickImagem(src)
 {
   $(conteudo).empty() 
   document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background="url('"+src+"') no-repeat";
 }
```

```css
 .conteudo-externo{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  z-index:3;
  background:#f1f;
  float:left;
 }
 .conteudo{
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:#f4f;
  margin: 50px auto;
  }
  .img{
   z-index:1;
   width:130px;
                        height:130px
                        background-position:center;
   opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Teste</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="http://www.vannwilliamscustomhomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/250x250.png" onclick="clickImagem(this.src)">
<div class="conteudo-externo">
  <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo">
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Parece ser exatamente a mesma dúvida que esta (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239062/5878). Pode explicar qual é a real diferença entre as duas?

Comment: Aquela pergunta era para centralizar uma div circular dentro de uma div.
Esta pergunta é para centralizar uma imagem dentro da div circular @Anderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faltou a propriedade `center`

```js
function clickImagem(src)
 {
  $('#conteudo').css('background',"url('"+src+"') no-repeat center");
 }
```

```css
.conteudo-externo{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  z-index:3;
  background:#f1f;
  float:left;
 }
 .conteudo{
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:#f4f;
  margin: 50px auto;
    background-position:center;
  }
  .img{
   z-index:1;
   width:130px;
      height:130px;
   opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Teste</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="http://www.vannwilliamscustomhomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/250x250.png" onclick="clickImagem(this.src)">
<div class="conteudo-externo">
  <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo">
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Perfeito !! Obrigado Felipe, não conheço muito de Java Script então não sabia como colocar este center na function

Comment: Denada kk, só repare que eu substitui a ação de background de javascript para jquery(biblioteca que auxilia no desenvolvimento javascript), recomendo que toda vez que for mexer no DOM ou manipular eventos, use a mesma.

Comment: Entendi, qualquer outra coisa que eu quiser alterar no css posso usar esta function mesmo certo?? Width e Height da imagem por exemplo

Comment: Isso mesmo, muito mais fácil e legível, editei a resposta simplificando ainda mais

Comment: Entendi !! Obrigado @Felipe